# Using GEE to investigate area of Desert returns wrong area

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, ndvi

I am very new at GEE and am trying to investigate how much of Chad is desert using NDVI. I presumed using Reducer.count() to count the number of pixels and then multiplying it by the scale would give me an area. Comparing my Total Area with that of Chad shows my results are off by a factor of 50. I'm not sure what I can do to correct that.

```
var country = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_CODE',50));
print(country)
var maxpixel = 8000000000
Map.addLayer(country,['green'],'Chad');
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-18', '2000-12-18'));
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI');
var meanndvi = ndvi.mean();
var clippedndvi = meanndvi.clip(country);
var totalpixel = clippedndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: country.geometry(),
  scale: 250,
  crs: 'SR-ORG:6974',
  maxPixels: maxpixel
});

var totalArea = ee.Number(totalpixel.get('NDVI')).multiply(250);
//print('Total Pixels =',totalpixel)
print('Total Area =',totalArea)
var reducedndvi = clippedndvi.lt(2000).selfMask().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: country.geometry(),
  scale: 250,
  crs: 'SR-ORG:6974',
  maxPixels: maxpixel
}).values().get(0);
var desertArea = ee.Number(reducedndvi).multiply(250);
//print('Desert Area in Pixels =',reducedndvi);
print('Desert Area =',desertArea);
var percentage = ee.Number(ee.Number(desertArea).divide(totalArea)).multiply(100);
print('Desertified Fraction=',percentage,'%');

var ndviVis = {
  min: 100,
  max: 1999,
  palette: [
    'black', 'white',
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(clippedndvi, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the area of your image, you normally use `ee.Image.pixelArea()`, mask out pixels you want to exclude and then sum up the area.

```
var totalAreaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea()
  .updateMask(clippedndvi.mask())
  .rename('totalArea')
var desertAreaImage = totalAreaImage
  .updateMask(clippedndvi.lt(2000))
  .rename('desertArea')
var areas = totalAreaImage
  .addBands(desertAreaImage)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: country.geometry(),
    scale: 250,
    crs: 'SR-ORG:6974',
    maxPixels: 1e13
  })
  
var desertArea = areas.getNumber('desertArea')
var totalArea = areas.getNumber('totalArea')
var percentage = desertArea.divide(totalArea).multiply(100)

print('Desert Area (million km²)', desertArea.divide(1e12))
print('Total Area (million km²)', totalArea.divide(1e12))
print('Desertified Fraction (%)', percentage)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d108a9292654ff2392ea0b4c468d6321